# How to set g:python_indent.disable_parentheses_indenting?

Tags: vimrc, variables, filetype-python

`:help ft-python-indent` lists the following command:

```
let g:python_indent.disable_parentheses_indenting = 1
```

but when I try to use that in my config I am getting the error message

> E121: Undefined variable g:python_indent

I am surprised that the variable name contains a dot and judging from the error message it seems like vim indeed considers the dot part the end of the variable name.

I have found the code where the variable is used in `/usr/share/vim/vim90/autoload/python.vim`:

```
if g:python_indent.disable_parentheses_indenting == 1
```

As far as I remember a dot is used to concatenate strings so I thought that maybe these are two variables and I can use either one to enable this feature. So I have tried:

```
let disable_parentheses_indenting = 1
```

That does not give an error but does not enable the feature either.

Probably because it's a local variable.

I don't want to set the first variable, `g:python_indent` because that is used for other features, too, which I don't want to change. But then again it seems pretty clear in the help that this is supposed to be a single variable.

What is going on here?

How can I enable this feature?

I am using vim 9.0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `.` syntax is an alternative to access a dictionary value associated to a key.

```
let g:python_indent.disable_parentheses_indenting = 1
```

Is equivalent to:

```
let g:python_indent['disable_parentheses_indenting'] = 1
```

To define it you first declare `g:python_indent` as a dictionary

```
let g:python_indent = {}
let g:python_indent.disable_parentheses_indenting = 1
```

Or if you want to be sure not to empty an existing dictionary

```
if !exists('g:python_indent')
  let g:python_indent = {}
endif
let g:python_indent.disable_parentheses_indenting = 1
```

Comment: thank you so much, that explains it! btw I think there is a typo in your answer, it should be only one `=` in the let statement.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'm glad I have been able to help you. I corrected the typo ;-)

Comment: thank you. Actually that let statement appears three more times in the answer :)

Comment: Or if you want it on a single line @jakun: `let g:python_indent = #{disable_parentheses_indenting: 1}`. Or with checking if it already exists (bit complicated): `let g:python_indent = get(g:, 'python_indent', {})->extend(#{disable_parentheses_indenting: 1})`.